# Cookie の同意ポップアップがメタ上で表示されない

Tags: バグ, 完了

日本語版を含め、Stack Exchange の各サイトにアクセスした際に通常であれば Cookie の同意画面がポップアップで表示されますが、日本語版の **メタサイト** にアクセスした時に表示されません。

より具体的には、**多言語サイトのメタ** のみで問題が起きているようです。

初めはサブドメインの部分が `aaa.bbb` の形式で `.` を含むものが NG なのかと思いましたが、正常に表示されるサイトもあるので、結局は多言語サイトのみが対象のようです。

- 表示されない例:
  `ja.meta.stackoverflow.com`
  `ru.meta.stackoverflow.com`
- 表示される例:
  `meta.stackoverflow.com`
  `meta.askubuntu.com`
  `japanese.meta.stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この問題は無事修正されました。Cookie 同意ポップアップ (およびサイトのフッターの「Cookie 設定」リンク) が、すべての多言語版 SO のメタサイトに再び表示されるようになりました。